# Last Command How to save Fei

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, steam

I have some Windows questions.

The question is about the game that was developed with the Unity issue.

I stuck the main title.

And can't continue.

And they ask me to operate some Windows to solve it.

And it needs to find the "Fei.program".

But I can't find it.

Somebody any idea?

Sorry for the stupid question Forgive me, please.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to address this question to some other QA site or forum. This is not a programming question. Or is it?

Comment: Hi, any recommendations?
I really need it.

Answer (score 1):

about your issue.

There has two method can help you.

A.
Step 1: Go to your windows' recycling bin.

Step 2: Find the file named Fei.program.

Step 3: Right-click to show the options menu.

Step 4: Select "Restore".

Step 5: Go to your Last Command game's root folder. And enter the World folder.
Likely... "E:\Steam\steamapps\common\Last Command\World".

step 6: Congratulations, you save Fei! And you can close the game. GG.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr8V2.png)

B.
If you can't find the Fei.program. Unfortunately.

Maybe you can find the Fei.program here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T8r2Sc3oy1hAzagczOOGLL3Y61UqZbaz/view?usp=sharing

Step 1: Download the Fei.program.

Step 2: Put the "Fei.program" into your Last Command game's root folder. And enter the World folder.
Likely... "E:\Steam\steamapps\common\Last Command\World"

step 3: Congratulations, you save Fei! And you can close the game. GG.

[image example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY9hc.png)